# What is the unit of size, spacing and other properties in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

When learning JavaFX you find that you can set the height and width of scene, you can set the spacing between nodes in HBox, and other similar aspects.
My question is about the unit of such values.
For example, in this simple code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TestGUI extends Application{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button btn1 = new Button("OK");
        Button btn2 = new Button("Cancel");
        HBox root = new HBox(15,btn1,btn2);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,250,50);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("GUI Example");
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

What is the units of 250, 50 and 15?

Comment: Interesting question. I cannot find any documentation specifically explaining what “width” and “height” float numbers mean precisely. For example, no details on [constructor of `Scene`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Scene.html#%3Cinit%3E(javafx.scene.Parent,double,double)).

Comment: I also did some research in multiple sites and classes and found nothing

Comment: From the documentation of Node here, they talk about using pixels https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html I think it can be the same thing with the other components, I delete my answer to find a good reference

Comment: With the advent of high-density screens, Cascading Style Sheets (CSS) years ago changed the meaning of their `px` (pixel) unit of size, changing from physical screen picture elements to a [logical unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel#Logical_pixel) of minimally apparent physical drawing. Unfortunately I’ve not seen a precise definition in CSS. Apparently JavaFX/OpenJFX is doing something similar, but with even less specification/documentation.

Comment: The closest definition I know of in Javadoc is the [Coordinate System](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html) documentation for `Node`, though it is not really well-defined, perhaps deliberately.  If a dimension is specified in CSS as a size or length, there [are more unit options](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#typesize).  The equivalent term in the JavaFX CSS spec is *"**px**: pixels, relative to the viewing device"*, which is the default unit used.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are in pixels, subject to a scaling factor for high DPI displays.

From the docs for Node:

> At the device pixel level, integer coordinates map onto the corners and cracks between the pixels and the centers of the pixels appear at the midpoints between integer pixel locations. Because all coordinate values are specified with floating point numbers, coordinates can precisely point to these corners (when the floating point values have exact integer values) or to any location on the pixel. For example, a coordinate of (0.5, 0.5) would point to the center of the upper left pixel on the Stage. Similarly, a rectangle at (0, 0) with dimensions of 10 by 10 would span from the upper left corner of the upper left pixel on the Stage to the lower right corner of the 10th pixel on the 10th scanline. The pixel center of the last pixel inside that rectangle would be at the coordinates (9.5, 9.5).

For scaling factor, see:

- https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/Window.html#getOutputScaleX()

Which states:

> The scale that the Window will apply to horizontal scene coordinates in all stages of rendering and compositing the output to the screen or other destination device.

Similarly OutputScaleY exists for the vertical coordinates.

Also:

- https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/Screen.html#getOutputScaleX()